# Formula button disabled on excel pivot table options

Tags: excel, ssas, pivot-table, cube

I am working with pivot tables using data connection from SSAS published cube.

I am having problem with calculated values because when the pivot table displays the data, the Formula button on the Pivot table options is disabled. I don't know where the problem is.

Also, when I use the "% difference" option when displaying data, it always displays `#N/A`.

Is there a problem with my SSAS cube? I can do most of reports except those that requires % difference.

Comment: What version of Excel and SSAS are you using?

Comment: excel 2007 and SSAS 2012.=)

Answer (score 0):

You might check to make sure that the field you're trying to do the math against is numeric and not text.
Just a thought.